# wikipedia user data for a recommendation engine

Tags: machine-learning, wikipedia

So I pulled the [Wikipedia Page Traffic Statistics](https://aws.amazon.com/de/datasets/wikipedia-page-traffic-statistics/?tag=datasets%23keywords%23encyclopedic) into an AWS instance and then downloaded a file which represents one hour from several months of usage data to look at locally, but it didn't really have what I was hoping for.

From the notes:

```
Each line has 4 fields: projectcode, pagename, pageviews, bytes
```

Here is an example of a quick search within the one hour of data:

```
$ grep versailles pagecounts-20110331-230000 

commons.m Image:Chateau-de-versailles-Rotonde.jpg 1 6695
en File%3ABallet_versailles.jpg 1 34511
en File:Ballet_versailles.jpg 2 69056
en File:Bosquet_des_bains_d_appolon_du_chateau_de_versailles.jpg 1 9010
en File:Chateau-de-versailles-cour.jpg 5 85244
en File:Theatre-versailles.jpg 2 15030
en Galerie_versailles 1 20375
en Palace_of_versailles 1 56442
en Treaty_of_versailles 6 300984
en galerie_versailles 1 542
en versailles_bakery 1 546
en versailles_cafe 1 544
en versailles_country_kitchen 1 555
en versailles_cuban_restaurant 1 556
en versailles_distinctive_elegance 1 560
en versailles_drive_in_the 1 552
en versailles_fine_dining 1 551
en versailles_restaurant_diner 1 556
en versailles_sub_%26_bagels_shop 1 559
es Archivo:Salle_jeu_de_paume_versailles_int%C3%A9rieur_2.jpg 2 17772
fr Fichier:Ballet_versailles.jpg 1 10039
fr Fichier:Logo_chateau_versailles.jpg 1 8911
fr Fichier:Palace_of_versailles,_part.JPG 2 20161
it File:Prefecture_yvelines_versailles.jpg 1 9932
ru %D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Eglise_notre_dame_versailles_fa%C3%A7ade.jpg 1 12709
```

Can see that Treaty of Versailles was winning that hour but Versailles Cuban Restaurant also got some attention.

This is unfortunately only one half of what is needed for a recommendation engine - the traffic of 'products' viewed, but the dataset does not provide the other half, namely a set of 'users' and what they viewed/bought.

I have never heard of logging into wikipedia but can see it is possible. Could be logged in or cookie based data available somewhere. Does anyone know if such data is available?

Comment: So basically your question is: *Can I have page traffic statistics **with** anonimized user data*?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Would be nice if it is available but I'm starting to look at similar platforms in case it's not.